# Fetch json data from url and write in a file

Tags: javascript, elixir-jason

I'm trying to fetch Json data from a Url and then write the data in a Json File.
Here is my code :

```js
let jsondata;    
fetch('www....')
    .then(function(u){ 
        return u.json();
    })
    .then(function(json) {
          jsondata = json;
        });

const fs = require('fs');


// write JSON string to a file
fs.writeFile('test.json', JSON.stringify(jsondata), (err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log("JSON data is saved.");
});
```

But I'm stuck with this error as the data I want to write in my file seems to have an invalid argument while I use JSON.stringify. Someone got an idea ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type
> string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received
> undefined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: `jsondata = json;` don't do this. Put the `fs.writeFile` inside the `.then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsondata` is a redundant variable. Here is a rewrite of your `fetch().then().then()` which leverages `fs.writeFile()` in the second `.then()`.

I used `node-fetch` for this implementation, but it should work in a browser environment as well.

```
fetch('http://somewebsite.null')
.then((response) => { 
    return response.json();
})
.then((json) => {
    fs.writeFile('./test.json', JSON.stringify(json), (err) => {
        if (err) {
            throw new Error('Something went wrong.')
        }
        console.log('JSON written to file. Contents:');
        console.log(fs.readFileSync('test.json', 'utf-8'))
    })
})
```

Comment: I've just added const fs = require('fs'); before fs.writeFile but your solution works perfectly, thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

you can get a fetch result with `async/await`.   `writeFile` should be called after get a fetch result

```
async function write(){
        let jsondata;    
        const response = await fetch('www....');
        jsondata = await response.json();
        
        const fs = require('fs');
        
        
        // write JSON string to a file
        fs.writeFile('test.json', JSON.stringify(jsondata), (err) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            console.log("JSON data is saved.");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've got this error : Parsing error: Unexpected token function async function write

Comment: How did you call the write function?